# Text to speech: Portuguese language not available?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, text-to-speech

I need to implement an app (TTS)  which can read text in Portuguese language . Unfortunately, when using `TextToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale loc)` method, I couldn't find Portuguese language in it. `Locale.` returned number of languages except Portuguese.

So, is there any way I can implement TTS in Portuguese? I am using Android 2.3.3 anyway.

**UPDATE**

As one member suggested, I used the API

This is the code

```
private void speak()
    {
        String text = textToSpeech.getText().toString();

        Audio audio = Audio.getInstance();
        InputStream sound;
        try {
            sound = audio.getAudio(text, Language.PORTUGUESE);
            audio.play(sound);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I got the error

```
08-23 15:00:47.421: W/System.err(728): java.net.UnknownHostException: translate.google.com
08-23 15:00:47.421: W/System.err(728):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
08-23 15:00:47.431: W/System.err(728):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
08-23 15:00:47.431: W/System.err(728):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
08-23 15:00:47.431: W/System.err(728):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:69)
08-23 15:00:47.431: W/System.err(728):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
08-23 15:00:47.431: W/System.err(728):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
08-23 15:00:47.431: W/System.err(728):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
08-23 15:00:47.441: W/System.err(728):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
08-23 15:00:47.441: W/System.err(728):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
08-23 15:00:47.441: W/System.err(728):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1018)
08-23 15:00:47.441: W/System.err(728):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:512)
08-23 15:00:47.441: W/System.err(728):  at com.gtranslate.Audio.getAudio(Audio.java:34)
08-23 15:00:47.451: W/System.err(728):  at com.example.tts.MainActivity.speak(MainActivity.java:70)
08-23 15:00:47.451: W/System.err(728):  at com.example.tts.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:63)
08-23 15:00:47.461: W/System.err(728):  at com.example.tts.MainActivity$SpeechClass.onClick(MainActivity.java:53)
08-23 15:00:47.461: W/System.err(728):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
08-23 15:00:47.461: W/System.err(728):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
08-23 15:00:47.461: W/System.err(728):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-23 15:00:47.461: W/System.err(728):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-23 15:00:47.461: W/System.err(728):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-23 15:00:47.471: W/System.err(728):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-23 15:00:47.471: W/System.err(728):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 15:00:47.471: W/System.err(728):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-23 15:00:47.471: W/System.err(728):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-23 15:00:47.471: W/System.err(728):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-23 15:00:47.471: W/System.err(728):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about [java-google-translate-text-to-speech](http://code.google.com/p/java-google-translate-text-to-speech/)? It is an API towards Google Translate, exposing Text To Speak functions among others. It supports [Portuguese](http://java-google-translate-text-to-speech.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/com/gtranslate/Language.java), and a code snippet like this should do the work:

```
Audio audio = Audio.getInstance();
InputStream sound  = audio.getAudio("portuguese sentence", Language.PORTUGUESE);
audio.play(sound);
```

The drawback is that you have to be online for the API to work.

Comment: but there are 2 libs. Which one to download? please help

Comment: Well, it seems like you need both in order to play sounds.

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence translate.google.com most certainly exist. Does your app have access to the internet?

Comment: Yes, permissions are enabled. Must be an issue in the lib

Answer (score 2):

How are you trying to get the locale?  If you are relying on the constants defined in the `Locale` class, there doesn't seem to be one defined for Portuguese.  You should be able to construct it something like: `new Locale("pt")` (or `new Locale("pt", "pt")` or `new Locale("pt", "br")`)

Such as:

```
tts.setLanguage(new Locale("pt"));
```

level of support for the language can be checked using [`isLanguageAvailable(Locale)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#isLanguageAvailable%28java.util.Locale%29).

Comment: I am on phone now so I CNT check. Can u be please kind enough to let me know the language level support for this language?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have the language that you need installed.

Try to install Google TTS: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tts&hl=en, and select it on your device configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("pt", "br");
tts.setLanguage(locale);
```

It worked for me!